# Append 1D tensors iteratively to make 2D tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have this tensor that's of length 64 and I'm trying to append to the 1st dimension to make a 2D tensor recursively. Essentially each iteration it creates a new 1D `64` length tensor and it iterates 6 times so by the end I should have a `6 x 64` tensor. How do I do this?

I tried

```
names_tensor = torch.cat((names_tensor, sampled_indexes), dim=1)
```

Where name_tensor is initiated as `torch.zeros(0)` and `sampled_indexes` is the `64` length tensor that gets appended each iteration

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 0):

```py
import torch
names_tensor = torch.zeros(0)
sampled_indexes = torch.ones(64)

names_tensor = torch.cat((names_tensor, sampled_indexes.repeat(6))).reshape(6,64)
names_tensor.size()
>> torch.Size([6, 64])
```

Use [`torch.cat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=torch%20cat#torch.cat) for Concatenates sequence of tensors first and then reshape tensor using [`torch.reshape()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=torch%20reshape#torch.reshape)